# Xamarin Forms can't install same app twice (with different package name )

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have one app that is in market on Alpha mode (because the app is only for a resctricted group of persons).

And now I need to have another twin app (also in Alpha), considered "Dev" so, when I'm going to do updates first the them will be available on that version and only after that they will be apllied to that Production.

My workarround to have this version was to create a new app on the store, then create a new app (with different package name) and publish there (I don't know if this is the best way to handle this).

Problems:
I can't have both apps installed simultaneous, when I try to install the the second app store just gives me a error. Same happens when I try to install from xamarin.
I've been searching and everyone says that I need to have a different package name, but I already had it.

Someone knows a solution for this problem? Or a different way to do

Comment: Is Application name different? Are you debugging your application or updating you application to Google Store? If you are debugging,normally different package names, it means different application.You should install both of them in same device.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I tried both ways, first I published a new app on the store with diferent package name, but when I try to install from there, it shows me an error on the end, I tried in debug mode too, but have the same result. And if I uninstall the first app, the it works

Comment: Is your application using Content Providers?

Comment: Could you share the detail error message?